# Compact metrizable contractible locally contractible topological space of finite covering dimension is a CW complex

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact metrizable contractible locally contractible topological space of finite covering dimension. Is $X$ homeomorphic to a CW complex?

Comment: As you probably know, it is an open problem whether a closed topological $4$-manifold is homeomorphic to a CW complex. I gather you are asking for a countexample in a larger class of spaces. Your assumptions imply that $X$ is an ANR..

Comment: It seems the following is a counterexample: Let $X$ be the union of the straight line segments $I_n$ in $\mathbb R^2$ where $I_n$ joins the origin and the point $(1, 1/n)$, where $n$ is a nonnegative integer, and $I_0$ joins the origin and $(1,0)$.

Comment: To show that this example has no CW structure note that the space is compact, so the complex is finite, which easily leads to a contradiction.

Comment: also the compactification of the tree of which $F_2$ acts, is a counterexample.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I don't think it's an open problem whether a contractible manifold is homeomorphic to a CW complex.

Comment: Yes, contractible manifolds are smoothable and hence CW, but the method of proving this is manifold specific (smoothing theory) and won't help you in the setting of finte-dimensional ANRs, which is the point I was trying to make.